# Interfacing with a custom camera in Linux on the beaglebone

Tags: drivers, embedded

I need to get a camera (OV7670) working on a beaglebone running Debian.

Using the camera capes as a guide, I've connected the camera to the GPMC pins on the beagleboard and the I2C pins. However I'm a bit stumped to what I need to do in software to get Linux to recognize it as a camera and be able to use it to read a frame from the GPMC.

From the readings I've done, it seems like I need to load a kernel module. I found that there is a OV7670 C driver file in the kernel source. What kind of modifications (if any) would I need to do?